# Get elements by javascript with Python Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to get lists in python selenium using javascript like below

```
lists = browser.execute_script("document.getElementById('permalink-overlay').getElementsByClassName('u-dir')")
```

But, terminal shows an error of `'NoneType' object`

How can I get lists from python selenium by javascript?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do it wrong

```
lists = browser.execute_script("var x = document.getElementById('permalink-overlay').getElementsByClassName('u-dir'); return x;")
```

or something like that